# visual studio 2008 save or backup exceptions to break on

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

Hi i have break on unhandled exceptions turned on, and turn off the ones i expect to happen as part of my code.

But every so often (usually on restarts visual studio resets all my Debug->Exceptions to all unselected

I want to backup these values, or manually copy the file so i can put it back rather than having to go through and reselect the ones i want.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried to find answers on stack overflow already, and cannot find any, i have search google and also come up empty, i am really stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i have got round this is by upgrading to VS2010 or VS2012, as the export settings saves the exceptions list, which vs2008 didn't seem to do that.